# Post reply can't work from 2nd post

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I am working with a comment posting system for my web. Here everything work well. But in case of reply of each comment, reply work perfectly for last/new submitted comment.

When I go to reply others comment it's submit name and show it but cannot submit textarea of form.

*(1) If i replace my reply form at the end of page and visible with css for test then reply work but reply button cannot slide below to show reply form for each comment.

*(2) And if i replace my reply from just after reply of comment then reply work for 1st comment.

Show as below in post.php

So I think my problem is in my post.php page to replace in my reply form or any anything else.

here is my post.php

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function(){
            $("a.reply").click(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#parent_id").attr("value", id);
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        //showReplyBox
        $('a.reply').livequery("click", function(e){
            var getpID =  $(this).attr('id').replace('','');    
            //$('.commentBox').hide();
            $("#reply_here-"+getpID).show();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<?php
    include("db.php");
    function submitComments($tutid2){
        //This is submit main post form.
    }
?>

<?
    function getComments($tutid){
    global $dbh;
    //fetch all comments from database where the qazi_id number is the one you are asking for
    $results = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comments_lite WHERE qazi_id='$tutid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));

    echo'<div class="comments"><div id="updates"><div class="content"><comment>';

    // Show only main comment

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) 
    {   $id = $row['id'];
        $qazi_id = $row['qazi_id'];
        $likes = $row['likes'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $img = $row['img'];
        $description = $row['description'];     
        $url = $row['url'];
        $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
        $date = $row['date'];

        echo'<div class="comment">
                <div class="cdomment_cheder">';
        echo'<p class="name"><a href="userinfo.php?user='.$url.'"  title="'.$username.'">'.$username.'</a> Says:</p>';
        echo'<span class="cdomment_time">'.$date.'</span><br/>
            <div class="avatarcnt">
                <img alt="" src="uploadprofile/'.$u_imgurl.'"/>
            </div></div></div>
            <div class="cdomment_text">';
            if ($description=="") {echo '';}
            else echo''.htmlentities($description).'<br>';
            if ($img=="") {echo '';}
            else echo'<br><img src="comimage/'.$img.'"/>';
            echo '</div>';

    //delete
    echo'<div class="delete" align="right"><a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'">Delete</a></div>';

    //reply
    echo'<div class="reply_box"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="reply" id="'.$id.'">Reply</a></div>';

   //Likes
    echo''; 

   //Reply form

    echo'<div id="loader"></div><div class="reply_here" id="reply_here-'.$id.'" style="display:none;">
            <form action="" method="post" id="repfrm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset id="cmntfs">
                    <legend class="pyct">Your comment</legend>
                    <input type="hidden" name="username" tabindex="1" id="author" value="'.$username.'"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="url" tabindex="2" id="url" value="" />
                    <div id="maintbox">
                        <textarea name="replycom" rows="2" tabindex="4" id="replycom" value=""></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value="0" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="tutid2" id="tutid" value="'.$tutid2.'" />
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="" tabindex="5" id="submit" class="repfrm">Post Reply</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>';

    // Show Reply of each comment
    $query = "SELECT * FROM comments_reply WHERE parent_id ='".$id."'";
    $res = mysqli_query($dbh,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
    {   $id = $row['id'];
        $qazi_id = $row['qazi_id'];
        $likes = $row['likes'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $img = $row['img'];
        $description = $row['description'];     
        $url = $row['url'];
        $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
        $date = $row['date'];

            echo' <div class="rcontent"><replycomment><ul>
                <div class="comment">
                <div class="cdomment_cheder">';
                if ($url=="") {
                    echo'<p class="name">'.$username.' Says:</p>'; }
                else  echo'<p class="name"><a href="userinfo.php?user='.$url.'" title="'.$username.'">'.$username.'</a> Says:</p>';
                echo'<span class="cdomment_time">'.$date.'</span><br/>
                    <div class="avatarcnt">
                        <img alt="" src="uploadprofile/'.$u_imgurl.'"/>
                    </div></div></div>
                    <div class="cdomment_text">';
                        if ($description=="") {echo '';}
                        else echo''.htmlentities($description).'<br>';
                        if ($img=="") {echo '';}
                        else echo'<br><img src="comimage/'.$img.'"/>';
                echo '</div>';
                //delete        
                echo'<div class="delete" align="right"><a href="deletereply.php? id='.$id.'">Delete</a></div>';

                echo'</ul><replycomment></div>';

            }   //reply while close 

            *(2) And if i replace my reply from here then reply work for 1st comment.    

        }   //comment while close

        *(1) If i replace my reply form here and visible with css for test then reply work but reply button cannot slide below to show reply form for each comment.

        echo'</div><comment></div>';

    } //fuction close
?>
```

Comment: I think loop or foreach can solved my above problem. I read many article and example but can't do here, any one can help me please.